# How to read full filename if we know only a part of the filename eg, starts XYZ_----.txt from a folder

Tags: c#-4.0

How to read all similar file names  from a folder. files names like "Record_*".txt  from  C:\Records  folder . For example my file names start with  Record_.txt. So here we are aware of only the first part of our filename.

Here is what I tried,but is not working

```
   string path =ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogDir"];
     string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Records", "Record_*" + ".txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

Example for my FileNames 
  Record_12345.txt
  Record_33124.txt
  Record_77624.txt
```

I want to read all files names like "Record_*".txt  from  C:\Records  folder

Comment: Do you mean ".txt" or ".text", cause you mention both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need a second backslash in your path (i.e. to ensure the slash is correctly escaped).  Everything else looks good

```
string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogDir"];
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Records\\", "Record_*" + ".txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```